# Divide by Zero error in Materialized Views in Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse-analytics, dedicated-sql-pool

I have a materialized view in Azure synapse Analytics dedicated sql pool which has a calculate column X / denominator.
When **I select the view select * from myview** it does not give me divide by zero error.
But when I select
Select * from myview where denominator = 0 I get divide by zero error

When I use **select * from myview order by denominator** I am not getting divide by zero error.

How can this be explained. I know the Arithabort setting but not sure how to check the value set to this in Synapse dedicated SQL Pool. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't use Synapse dedicated SQL Pool - is the materialized view being used when you have the `where denominator = 0` predicate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/performance-tuning-materialized-views#:~:text=Not%20all%20performance%20tuning%20requires%20query%20change - if not does that product support the `NOEXPAND` hint?

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be explained.

When you run `Select * from myview where denominator = 0` it is resulting in a different execution plan than when you select from the view wide open with `select * from myview` or `select * from myview order by denominator`. That different execution plan likely has a different order of steps (physical operations) than the execution plans of the other wide open queries. The row where `denominator = 0` that was previously being filtered out early on before the division operation, is now not being filtered out until after the division operation, resulting in a "divide by 0" error.

The SQL engine is allowed to re-arrange the order of physical operations under the hood, when processing a query, so long as the end result of rows is logically the same. Sometimes that results in issues like this, where a row that was previously being filtered out early on, and is now filtered out later on, but causes an invalid / error case in a computation.

If you wanted to provide the materialized view's definition, some sample data from it and the underlying tables behind it, and the execution plans of your queries via [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan), then more information can be provided on how to fix the issue.

Comment: if a value divided by 0 my understanding is that it should throw the error if the "ARITHABORT' is set. So why the view when select in full not returning this issue. 
There is a second DW that has the same features and it throws the error when using 
Select * from myview.

Comment: How can I get the query plan in Dedicated sql pool?

Comment: "*if a value divided by 0 my understanding is that it should throw the error if the "ARITHABORT' is set. So why the view when select in full not returning this issue.*" - That's only if during **execution** a divide by 0 is encountered. But the query plan for your query that selects everything from the view isn't encountering a divide by 0 error because there's some kind of filtering happening inside your query that defined the view, which is removing those rows before the division happens. Your query that is erroring is **executing** with a different **execution** plan where that filtering...

Comment: ...happens later on after the division. So then the division step does encounter the rows with 0 and result in an error.

Comment: @SOUser For getting the execution plan, it sounds like this may be one way to do it: [DBCC PDW_SHOWEXECUTIONPLAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-pdw-showexecutionplan-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7). Also please see my comments above replying to your question. (I forgot to tag you in them.)